# For each text box in all slides of power point (VBA)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Apologize in advance for my bad english, i used part google translate ...

I stuck in cycling all the text boxes scattered in the Ppt slides.
What I should do my program is to initially open a Ppt file from Word or search for codes entered in the text boxes used as tags.
Once I find the corresponding code (I do not know if I wrote it right) should make a copy of the entire slide (I do not know how to tell it to take that of the text box) and paste it on a page (for now at random) In Word.
I searched on Google and found an apparently good code but I was "ERROR 13" in the second "For Each"

```
 public sub elaboraSlidePpt ()


    Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim pptPath As String
    Set doc = Application.ActiveDocument
    Dim docPpt As Slide

    pptPath = file_dir + "\" + file_name

    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    pptApp.Visible = False
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(pptPath)

    Dim sld As Slide, shp As Shape
    For Each sld In pptApp.ActivePresentation.Slides
      For Each shp In sld.Shapes '<-- ERROR 13
        If shp.Type = "img10" Then

            pptApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(????).Copy
            Application.ActiveDocument.Activate
            Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteEnhancedMetafile)

        End If
      Next shp
    Next sld
 end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've corrected a number of things.  Give this a try:

```
public sub elaboraSlidePpt ()

    Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    ' Create a POWERPOINT slide variable to use later
    Dim pptShape as PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim pptPath As String
    Set doc = Application.ActiveDocument
    Dim docPpt As Slide

    ' use & to combine strings, not +
    pptPath = file_dir & "\" & file_name

    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    pptApp.Visible = False
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(pptPath)

    'Dim sld As Slide, shp As Shape
    For Each pptSlide In pptPres.Slides
      For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
        ' You'll need to fix this ... 
        ' .Type will return a Long, not a string
        If pptShape.Type = "img10" Then

            pptSlide.Copy
            Application.ActiveDocument.Activate
            Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteEnhancedMetafile)

        End If
      Next ' Shape
    Next ' Slide
 end sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
The code works, the only problem remains how to cycle the contents of the text boxes present in each slides.
(I use them as tags because if text boxes match a string, copy the slide to the tape elsewhere)
In Word there are bookmarks or "normal text control" but in Ppt I have arranged with text boxes.
How do I solve this problem?
Thank you and good day

Comment: You might want to use .Tags on the PPT slides for this instead. I've got an article about them on my PPT FAQ site:  Working with Tags (and a bit about Functions)
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00815_Working_with_Tags_-and_a_bit_about_Functions-.htm